# What does free variable represent geometrically?

Tags: linear-algebra

As a rote student, I recently have started to try to learn the 'un-rote' way, but the ways in which the institutions do so is very limited and I'm stuck at the very first classes of linear algebra.

Technically, they say: **A free variable is a variable with no pivot column**, *as if it would make any sense for students to interpret!*.

Consider the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 3 & -5 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

which is equivalent to:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -8 & -1\\
        0 & 1 &  4 & -1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now the free variable is[image] z. But what does it actually represent? As I plot the equations in geogebra, I basically can make no sense out of it:

[image]

And this is what all the vectors look like as they are in 2D space:
[image]

**How can I make sense of what the free variable is geometrically?**

EDIT: If not geometrically(as mentioned below, what is it(with a little more sense rather than the non-sensemaking technical above in bold above)?)

Comment: To some extent the concept of a free variable is not intrinsically geometric.  The result of row reduction is sensitive to the order in which you present the variables; this in turn affects the location of the pivot columns, and hence also which variables are free.  Since the graphs of the equations are **not** sensitive to the naming of the variables, it should be impossible to read off the free variables by looking at only the graphs.  Essentially, a variable doesn't "know" that it's free, because the label is bestowed by the process (though the number of free variables is invariant).

Comment: Actually, could you edit your question to explain where the graphs come from?  I don't understand why you are graphing $z=2$, which does not come out of any of the equations.

Comment: @ErickWong, since z was the free variable, it could have any value(right?), so I just put z=2

Comment: Ah, I think it would be more productive to plot the locus of points $(x,y,z)$ that arise from choosing every possible choice of free variables (i.e. $z$).  That’s your actual solution space (which will be a single line in 3D).

Comment: That would mean entire R^3?

Comment: Nope, since $x$ and $y$ are determined by $z$.  So you would get only one pair of $x,y$ for each $z$.  There is a geometric interpretation for which sets of variables *could* be free, but it is much less natural to give a description of which specific variables are free when you row reduce in a certain order.

Comment: But, what exactly is a free variable? A vector? A plane? A point?

Comment: Obviously, a variable corresponds to a direction (or you could think of it as an axis).  That's how you are plotting them, after all.

Comment: Replace “free” with the phrase “freely-determined.” These variables, are unconstrained by your solution.

Comment: @Eroc Wong ,They act as a parameter?